# JsonPath - read Java Long type

Tags: java, json, types, jsonpath

I've got JSON data that looks like this

> {"sessionID":7242750700467747000}

The number is previously obtained from server response and is generated server-side as Java Long. Client identifies itself thought this `sessionID` and sends it with requests. The problem is when the client's request arrives at the server I have to parse this value again to type Long. I use JsonPath, specifically:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

When I parse the JSON data like this

> Long sessionID = JsonPath.read(json, "$.sessionID");

I get an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

So it looks like the number is parse by JsonPath as Integer. That will surely lead to wrong results, as Integer is smaller than Long. Is there any way in JsonPath to parse and return the data as Long?

Comment: I think you'll find that its a string that's extracted from the JSON and you then need to parse this to convert it into whatever type you require.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do it changing the JsonPath provider a bit. Now I use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

From there I can use

```
import com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
// ...
Long sessionID = JsonPath.with(json).getLong("sessionID");
```

Notation in this library is the same except for the lack of `$.` at the beginning, wich I don't find necessary at all.

Answer (score 13):

It's possible (`json-path:2.4.0`):

```
JsonPath.parse(json).read("$.sessionID", Long.class);
```

See more: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when

Answer (score 1):

For what I've seen, the API does not provide this option.

So I see two options for you:

1. On JSON serialization, make sessionId a String. Read a String and then parse to Long.
2. Use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), to make the JSON read. This will allow you to read a Long.

Comment: Is it possible in Jackson to read the values using similar x-path way? Or even some other way? Because from what I used it till now, I always parsed the whole JSON object and had it mapped by Jackson to an Object of some encapsulating class (using ObjectMapper.readValue()). Here I only need to extract a single value, ideally without creation of additional classes.